# Jest tests did not exit (one second) after the test run has completed using a simple Express application

Tags: node.js, jestjs, knex.js, supertest, objection.js

I have a simple `Express` application that exposes a RESTful API. It uses `Knex` and `Objection` to access the database, and `Jest` / `Supertest` for testing the API.

I have a test that starts the server, fetches the available data from a given route and asserts the received values. Everything works fine, except that `Jest` never exits after executing this test.

This is my test:

```js
import { app } from "../../src/application.js";

import { describe, expect, test } from "@jest/globals";
import request from "supertest";

describe("Customer Handler", () => {
  test("should retrieve all existing customer(s)", async () => {
    const expected = [
       // ...real values here; omitted for brevity
    ];
    const response = await request(app).get(`/api/customers`);
    expect(response.statusCode).toStrictEqual(200);
    expect(response.headers["content-type"]).toContain("application/json");
    expect(response.body).toStrictEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

The `application.js` file looks very much like a usual `Express` setup/configuration file:

```js
import { CustomerHandler } from "./handler/customer.handler.js";
import connection from "../knexfile.js";

import express from "express";
import Knex from "knex";
import { Model } from "objection";

const app = express();

Model.knex(Knex(connection[process.env.NODE_ENV]));

// ...removed helmet and some other config for brevity
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/api/customers", CustomerHandler);
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({
    errors: {
      error: err,
      message: err.message,
    },
  });
  next();
});

export { app };
```

I've tried `--detectOpenHandles`, but nothing else is printed in the console, so I can't see any hints about what the issue might be — which I suspect it's `Knex` / `Objection` because I'm using `SQLite`, so probably the connection to the database is not getting closed.

> In the meantime I'm using `--forceExit`, but I would like to figure it out why is `Jest` not able to exit.

Comment: You can try adding a parameter `done` to the function you pass as a second argument to `test`. Then, call `done()` when you are done the test.

Comment: I've tried this, but I'm getting this error message: `Test functions cannot both take a 'done' callback and return something. Either use a 'done' callback, or return a promise. Returned value: Promise {}`. Basically, I just do `... async (done) => { ...`, and call `done()` in the very end of the `test(...) {}` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, looks like I was on the right track for this one.

Refactoring `application.js` to export the `Knex` object (after it's configured), and calling `knex.destroy()` after the test passes is the solution for this setup.

```js
// application.js

...

const knex = Knex(connection[process.env.NODE_ENV]);

Model.knex(knex);

...

export { app, knex };
```

...then in the test(s), make sure you import `knex` and call `destroy()`:

```js
// customer.handler.test.js
import { app, knex } from "../../src/application.js";

import { afterAll, describe, expect, test } from "@jest/globals";
import request from "supertest";

describe("Customer Handler", () => {
  afterAll(async () => {
    await knex.destroy();
  });

  test("should retrieve all existing customer(s)", async () => {
    const expected = [ /* ...real values here */ ];
    ...
    expect(response.body).toStrictEqual(expected);
  });
});
```